# why html event.currentTarget is null when you log

Tags: javascript, html, events

```
function hide (e){
    console.log(e);//but in the Console click on triangle the currentTarget is null,why?
    console.log(e.currentTarget) //is an object.
}
var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for(var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++){
    ps[i].addEventListener('click', hide, false);
}
```

i thought the currentTarget is not 'available' in html for 2 years(i used to be as3 developer).just right now i try to find out why it not 'available',but when i find this reference [MDN Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget),the e.currentTarget shows a object,that confused me.now with the currentTarget 'available' for me,it make my life easier,but i just want to know why console lie to me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the [**help article**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions, and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the tags are **dynamically-generated**, so you have to hoist the scope, and attach the event listener to an **element that is not dynamically generated**.

Here's an example with jQuery, attaching the listener to `document`:

```js
$(document).on("click", "p", function(e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  One
</p>
<p>
  Two
</p>
<p>
  Three
</p>
```

Because `document` is always available, it will always have the listener attached. It then simply 'waits' for the dynamic elements to be created, before applying their click events.

I've also created a fiddle demonstrating this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/my35sk1p/2/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: yeah,when i  addEventListener on document the **currentTarget** is not null now.so i suppose console log is not dependable.but still make every thing not clear for me.thanks Obsidian

Comment: It's not `console.log` that's the problem; it's the fact that the elements don't exist on the page when the event handler is added. That's why it works when you add them higher up and delegate :)

Comment: i think you misunderstand my point, please try my code in **browser Console**.first log the **e** and click on the **currentTarget** triangle it shows null,but when i log **e.currentTarget** it's not null.

Comment: Ahh, I was indeed slightly misunderstanding. Though I believe the cause is still the same. If you hoist the scope, both `e` and `e.currentTarget` have the correct target :)

Comment: yeah,addevent on document log is always correct,but you can't always addeventlistener on document,it's not good for performance